# How to solve the probability of N events occurring at the same time, N is a random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, discrete-distributions, conditional

How to solve the probability of N events occurring at the same time, N is a random variable and its PDF is known. The probability of each event is also known and the probability of each event is not equal.

---

Composite Binomial (Poisson) distribution is a good solution for independent events with equal probability.

Comment: N can be regarded as a PPP process in a two-dimensional plane area.

Comment: If N has a known pdf (probably you mean pmf probability mass function, instead of probability density function) then you can use that to compute the probability.

Comment: If you can elaborate on it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: For instance if N follows a Poisson distribution with some known rate parameter $\lambda$ then the probability mass function is $$P(n) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}$$ The probability for $n=0$ events is $P(0) = e^{-\lambda}$, the probability for $n=1$ events is $P(1) = \lambda e^{-\lambda}$, the probability for $n=2$ events is $P(2) = \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda}$, the probability for $n=3$ events is $P(3) = \frac{1}{6} \lambda^3 e^{-\lambda}$, the probability for $n=4$ events is $P(4) = \frac{1}{24} \lambda^4 e^{-\lambda}$, and so on.

Comment: The situation is not very clear. You need to describe better what sort of events you are talking about. You speak about 'the probability of each event', how many of such probabilities for potential events are there? What do you mean by the probability of N events occurring while N is a random variable? Do you mean that N is the number of events occurring at the same time and it fluctuates, or do you mean the target number N  that you want to compare 'the number of events occuring at the same time' with is itselve a variable?

Comment: N is the number of events occurring at the same time and it fluctuates.

Comment: You write that it's pdf is known, so what is the problem or required solutions leading to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the events are independent then the probability of N events is the product of all the events. Because N is random variable the final solution is integral over all possible values of N.

The probability that $N = i$ is given by the pmf of $N$ we will mark it as $f(i)$.

Now we integrate over the different values of $N$. Each value that represent the number of events and we multiply the probability of all the events.

$\int_{i=0}^\inf (\prod_{k=0}^{k=i}P(enent_k))f(i)di$

where $f$ is the pmf of $N$ i.e. $f(i) = P(N = i)$

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the interpretation of the OP. But suppose it is, say you have 100 possible events then the probability of 2 events happening needs to be constructed from every possible pair of two events occuring. You only take the product of the first two events.

Comment: We are solving for the probability of all events happening.

Comment: The formula is ill-formed, both typographically (obviously) and mathematically (the integrand is a constant and has no explicit variable of integration); and in light of the vagueness of the question, it is impossible to determine what it's intended to mean.  Could you fix it up?

Comment: @whuber the way i understood the question: N is a random variables that can have different values. Thus we integrate over the different values, each has a probability f(i) according to the pmf. once we have the value i (the number of events) we multiply the probability of all of them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still cannot make sense of the question.  Part of the problem is that the OP uses the same symbol $N$ to refer both to a "random variable" and a count of "events occurring at the same time."  Your answer doesn't offer any clarification of what that might possibly mean.  And once you take the product of all the probabilities (which means what, exactly?), what are you integrating over??

Comment: N = number of events. this is a random variable. so first we determine the number of events, for example we got 3 events.  Then we calculate the probability that all 3 events occur together. which is P(event_1) * P (event_2) * P (event_3). Then we calculate the expectation of it by integrating over number of events.

Comment: "All three events occur together" in this context would refer to their *intersection.* It is unlikely your product formula would give the correct answer.  "Integrating over the number of events" appears to make no sense at all, so that must be where I'm stuck.  Would you be able to supply a simple concrete example to enlighten us?

Comment: given the vagueness of the question it is definitely possible that my interpretation is wrong, i don't see a point continue arguing about it. i am perfectly fine with deleting my answer (though i currently technically can't)